# Django inline forms with multiple foreign keys

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to use Django's ModelForm and inline forms in my templates. However, I cannot find any documentation that maps neatly to a database model with multiple foreign keys back to the same table. These are my models:

```
# models.py

class Universities(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Majors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Resumes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    undergrad = models.ForeignKey(Universities, related_name='undergrad_university')
    undergrad_major = models.ForeignKey(Majors, related_name='undergrad_major')
    grad = models.ForeignKey(Universities, related_name='grad_university')
    grad_major = models.ForeignKey(Majors, related_name='grad_major')
```

How can I have Django generate a form for submitting Resumes where users can type in their university name and major? All four of which would be used to create new entries in their respective databases (2 in Universities, 2 in Majors) before saving the new resume similar to how the [inline formset example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) works for a singular foreign key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT2 : For making a form. I guess I'd have done a personalized form with overriding of save() method, something like this (forms.py):

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    fname = forms.CharField(label="name",max_length=70,validators=[#Choose your validators here])
    fundergrad = forms.CharField(label="fundergrad",max_length=100,validators=[#Choose your validators here])
    fundergrad_major = forms.CharField(label="fundergrad_major",max_length=80,validators=[#Choose your validators here])
    fgrad = forms.CharField(label="fgrad",max_length=100,validators=[#Choose your validators here])
    fgrad_major = forms.CharField(label="fgrad_major",max_length=80,validators=[#Choose your validators here])

    def save(self, datas):
        res = Resumes()
        res.name = datas['fname']
        
        undergrad = Universities()
        undergrad_major = Majors()
        grad = Universities()
        grad_major = Majors()
        
        undergrad.name = datas['fundergrad']
        undegrad_major.name = datas['fundergrad_major']
        grad.name = datas['fgrad']
        grad_major.name = datas['fgrad_major']
    
        undergrad.save()
        undergrad_major.save()
        grad.save()
        grad_major.save()
    
        res.undergrad = undergrad
        res.undergrad_major = undergrad_major
        res.grad = grad
        res.grad_major = grad_major
    
        res.save()
        return res
```

In views.py :

```
def formView(request) :
  if request.method == 'POST':
      form = YourForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
          datas={}
          datas['fundergrad']=form.cleaned_data['fundergrad']
          datas['fundergrad_major']=form.cleaned_data['fundergrad_major']
          datas['fgrad']=form.cleaned_data['fgrad']
          datas['fgrad_major']=form.cleaned_data['fgrad_major']

          form.save(datas)

  #Then do what you have to do in your view
```

EDIT1 : (doesn't answer the question, but it could help someone maybe so I let it here)

I would have tried with something like this in admin.py:

```
class UniversitiesInline1(admin.StackedInline):
  model = Universities
  fk_name = "undergrad"

class UniversitiesInline2(admin.StackedInline):
  model = Universities
  fk_name = "grad"

class MajorsInline1(admin.StackedInline):
  model = Majors
  fk_name = "undergrad_major"

class MajorsInline2(admin.StackedInline):
  model = Majors
  fk_name = "grad_major"

class ResumesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
  inlines = [
    UniversitiesInline1,
    UniversitiesInline2,
    MajorsInline1,
    MajorsInline2,
  ]

admin.site.register(Resumes, ResumesAdmin)
```

Explanations : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-a-model-with-two-or-more-foreign-keys-to-the-same-parent-model

Comment: Ah I was afraid that a custom form with a custom save would be the only solution (I was starting to go down the same route before posting my question). The description of ModelForms + inline forms seemed to fit perfectly, but I guess it isn't possible with my model. I'm going to leave up the question for another day or two and hope that this isn't the case before accepting. I'll also test the code and let you know if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, a custom form will always allow you more freedom for : display style, type of fields, widget of fields, validators and custom validators, complex validation (if you want to check fields between them for example). You can do all this very easily in a custom form, a simple Django form doesn't allow that much customization.

Comment: This doesn't address when the model fails to save when the user input data is doesn't validate correctly