# Django One-To-Many Model and Admin inlines

Tags: django, admin, one-to-many, inline-formset

I 'm trying to define 2 models in django like so:

```
class Selector(models.Model):
    # A Beautiful Soup selector
    selector = models.CharField(max_length=ELEMENT_SELECTOR_MAX_LENGTH, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.selector


class Provider(models.Model):
    # Articles' parent container selector
    articles_parent_container_selector = models.ForeignKey(Selector, related_name="articles_parent_container",
                                                          help_text=_("Beautiful Soup selector for all articles' "
                                                                      "parent container"))

    # Article's parent container selector
    article_parent_container_selector = models.ForeignKey(Selector, related_name="article_parent_container_selector",
                                                         help_text=_("Beautiful Soup selector for each article"))
```

etc. etc.
The idea is to have more than one selectors for each field of the Provider model.

What I 'm trying to achieve at the admin application, is have charField inlines for each field of the provider model.

So my admin.py is like

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Provider, Selector


class SelectorInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Selector


class ProviderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        SelectorInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(Provider, ProviderAdmin)
```

I get the error

```
<class 'news_providers.admin.SelectorInline'>: (admin.E202) 'news_providers.Selector' has no ForeignKey to 'news_providers.Provider'.
```

I also tried

```
class SelectorInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Selector
    fk_name = 'articles_parent_container'
```

as described here: [Django inline forms with multiple foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493145/django-inline-forms-with-multiple-foreign-keys)

but the error now is:

```
<class 'news_providers.admin.SelectorInline'>: (admin.E202) 'news_providers.Selector' has no field named 'articles_parent_container'.
```

Also tried changing my relation to ManyToMany(which seems more relevant to my use-case as well) and apply the hack found here: http://www.mc706.com/tip_trick_snippets/18/django-manytomany-inline-admin/ , but no luck :/

This should be pretty straight forward, but I 'm afraid django developers didn't take notice of this use case?

Thanks!

Comment: The foreign key is from the `Provider` model to `Selector`. Therefore you can have Provider inlines on the `Selector` model admin. However, it's not possible to have `Selector` inlines on the `Provider` model admin.

Comment: That's what I thought :/
I also tried http://www.mc706.com/tip_trick_snippets/18/django-manytomany-inline-admin/ ,but it doesn't seem to work (I changed the ForeignKey to ManyToMany)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So apparently, there is no built-in functionality to display an inline manyToMany model inside another's model page.

The best you can do is define the model like so

models.py

```
class Selector(models.Model):
    # A Beautiful Soup selector
    selector = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True, blank=True)

class Provider(models.Model):

    # Articles' parent container selector
    articles_parent_container_selector = models.ManyToManyField(Selector, blank=True,
                                                                help_text=_("Beautiful Soup selector for all articles' "
                                                                            "parent container."),
                                                                related_name='articles_parent_container')
```

admin.py

```
class ArticlesParentContainerSelectorInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Provider.articles_parent_container_selector.through
    verbose_name = "Articles' parent container selector"

class ProviderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ArticlesParentContainerSelectorInline,

    ]
    exclude = ('articles_parent_container_selector',)

admin.site.register(Provider, ProviderAdmin)
```

and what you 'll get looks like this:
[image: inline admin for manyToMany]

which is a bit of a disappointment, as I was expecting to get Text Inputs instead of dropdowns (or even both of them), so I could add Selectors without having to click the plus sign...

I 'm leaning towards creating my own widget for the admin application.

Anyway, thanks to everyone who bothered to read!